# Is SQL Server's full text search CONTAINS() vulnerable to SQL Injections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, sql-injection

In our codebase we use Hibernate and use it's Restrictions.sql() method use the MS SQL Server's full text search. The sqlRestriction is build using CONTAINS(column_name, search_text) predicate where the search_text is the user entered text.

> ```
> Restrictions.sqlRestriction("CONTAINS(" + column_name + ", ?)", "\"" + userInput + "*\"", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
> ```

Is this **CONTAINS()** method vulnerable to SQL Injections?

Comment: *Any* SQL is vulnerable if you are injecting incorrectly. Using `CONTAINS` doesn't make the query more or less susceptible. `CONTAINS` can be parmetrised, so provided you parametrise, you're fine.

Comment: @Larnu AFAIK the column name cannot be parameterized. Don't have an instance setup with it so can't test

Comment: That doesn't change my point, @Charlieface . Inject what must be correctly, parametrise what can be correctly. If you do, you vastly minimise/romove the injection issues. `CONTAINS` doesn't make a statement vulnerable to injection, injection does.

Comment: Hibernate itself parameterize the given userInput when the actual query got build. Further the jdbc driver uses sp_executesql procedure to run this query. Whenever I try to inject another sql query like drop table or select * within the userInput, I get syntax errors. So its unclear what other injections possibly done within contains(). Any such working examples of injection within contains() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not much knowledgeable in SQL Injection , but as per I have read it will only affect if you are searching for apart of text in a column using 'like', here we are searching whole user text, so I think its fine but its better to conform by doing some injection attacks yourself as testing.
Better search little more on the topic or wait for some good answers

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, such injection is vulnerable.** That is not to say that it's `CONTAINS` itself which causes the issue, it's the *injection* which is the problem.

Unfortunately, `CONTAINS()` does not accept a variable for the column name, so it needs to be injected. In order to make this injection safe, **you must check it against a whitelist.**

If it is verified against a whitelist then there is no vulnerability. **Do *not* just accept user input directly into the query.**